# Why can't I get the cookie's value with Jinput in Joomla 2.5+?

Tags: cookies, get, joomla2.5

**QUESTION**

Why can't I get the cookie's value with Jinput in Joomla 2.5+?

**DETAILS**

I used to use

```
$cookievalue = JRequest::getVar( 'cookievalue', 'valueifnotexist', 'COOKIE' );
```

but it is deprecated in joomla 3.

So I tried using Jinput

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$cookievalue = $jinput->get( 'cookievalue', 'valueifnotexist', 'COOKIE' );
```

**NOTE:** According to http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput there is no 'COOKIE' filter. I've tried using 'STRING' as the filter, but the results are much the same. The value I'm expecting to get for the cookie is in the format `date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() )`

**RESULTS**

When I check to see if the value has been retrieved I always get 'valueifnotexist'
I've used firebug to confirm that the cookie/value exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get cookie by using:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie->get('YOUR COOKIE NAME');
```

Of course you can use getString() instead of get(), or apply any filter you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Both get and getString worked for me. I'm assuming you mean the filters listed at http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput